# Is it possible to encrypt in AES without special characters?

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes, quarkus

Good afternoon, I am currently working with an api in JAVA and Quarkus, in it I am receiving through the GET method a parameter in the url that is encrypted with AES, the issue is that the encryption comes with special characters like +/ which now read the url the service takes it as path

This is my code for AES encryption, the encrypt and decrypt methods, which I am using for my encryption:

```
package com.tmve.util;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

@NoArgsConstructor
public class EncryptUtil {
    private static byte[]   initializationVector = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private static byte[] key;
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;

    public String encrypt(String input, String key)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        byte[] desKeyData = key.getBytes();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(desKeyData, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec specie = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, specie);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText, String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        byte[] desKeyData =  key.getBytes();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(desKeyData,16), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);

        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
        return new String(plainText);
    }

    public String decryptAESText2(String cipherText, String key) throws Exception {
        setKey(key);
        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));

        return new String(plainText);
    }

    public String encryptAESText2(String plainText, String key) throws Exception {
        setKey(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec specie = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }

    public SecretKey getKeyFromPassword(String password, String salt)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec)
                .getEncoded(), "AES");
        return secret;
    }
    public String decryptSSOText(String cipherText) throws Exception {
        String DEFAULT_KEY = "k2/3kwpEMHKrLgNkYDzs+YVfzXSp9Xyx";
        String DEFAULT_IV = "G1oPqIGmVOk=";
        byte[] encData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText.replaceAll("[\n\r]", ""));
        byte[] tdesKeyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(DEFAULT_KEY);

        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(DEFAULT_IV));
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
        byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));

        return new String(plainText);
    }

    public String EncryptSSOText(String cipherText) throws Exception {
        String DEFAULT_KEY = "k2/3kwpEMHKrLgNkYDzs+YVfzXSp9Xyx";
        String DEFAULT_IV = "G1oPqIGmVOk=";
        byte[] desKeyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(DEFAULT_KEY);
        
        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(desKeyData, "DESede");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(DEFAULT_IV));
        decipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
        byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainText);
    }
    private void setKey(String myKey) {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public IvParameterSpec generateIv() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
        return new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    }
}
```

And sometimes figures as follows:

```
WKqxB/qNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ==
```

The problem lies when I have to pass this in a url like the following:

```
https://10.162.128.94:30000/userProfile/v3.6/users/WKqxB/qNPQUz6wRbHZrpBQ==
```

The above causes me an error when exposing my service, for example, by kubernete and an ingress, so I want to know if there is another option, I know that encoding and decoding in base64 is an option, but I would like to use AES

Comment: Use POST instead? If you're using POST and https then why encode at all?

Comment: The API specification asks for the GET method, the POST method is not contemplated

Comment: Then Base64-encoding is the obvious recourse

Comment: "I know that encoding and decoding in base64 is an option": You are already using Base64 encoding and decoding.

Comment: Yes, but I am using AES with base 64, I suppose a more advanced encryption, because I have seen an example of encryption in base 64 only and it does not add special characters

Answer (score 6):

You can use something called URL-safe base64 encoding instead. This will use `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/` in the generated base64 string.

Check out `java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder()` and `java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder()`.